# Access old site after redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, server-administration

I need to do permament redirect from clients old site to new one, redirection is from hissite.eu to newsite.com, same hosting but other domains. Now, he wants to still have access to his old site via some subdomain which would not be problem if i could make it work, but old site was badly made with custom CMS, lots of hardcoding and it just does not work if i move it to any directory.

So my question is if i make permament redirection from oldsite.eu to newsite.com , how can i provide him with access to his old site ? Is it possible somehow to not redirect if he types ip address instead of domain, but i suppose again administration panel wouldnt work. Is it possible to do redirection on everyone except specific ip maybe ?

Updating with current htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

Rewriterule ^index$                             index.php [L]
Rewriterule ^login$                             login.php [L]
Rewriterule ^register$                          register.php [L]
Rewriterule ^classified_new$                        classified_new.php [L]
Rewriterule ^account_classifieds$                   account_classifieds.php [L]
Rewriterule ^account_classifieds_manage$                account_classifieds_manage.php [L]
Rewriterule ^account_confirm$                   account_confirm.php [L]
Rewriterule ^account_details$                   account_details.php [L]

Rewriterule ^account_invoice_browse$                account_invoice_browse.php [L]
Rewriterule ^account_invoice_details$               account_invoice_details.php [L]
Rewriterule ^account_main$                      account_main.php [L]
Rewriterule ^account_messages$                  account_messages.php [L]
Rewriterule ^account_profile$                   account_profile.php [L]
Rewriterule ^ajax_request$                      ajax_request.php [L]
Rewriterule ^classified_browse$                     classified_browse.php [L]
Rewriterule ^classified_details$                    classified_details.php [L]
Rewriterule ^classified_new_form$                   classified_new_form.php [L]
Rewriterule ^classified_new_premium$                classified_new_premium.php [L]
Rewriterule ^classified_payment$                    classified_payment.php [L]
Rewriterule ^classified_new_confirmation$           classified_new_confirmation.php [L]
Rewriterule ^classified_payment_process$                classified_payment_process.php [L]
Rewriterule ^classified_payment_response$           classified_payment_response.php [L]
Rewriterule ^classifieds_json$                  classifieds_json.php [L]
Rewriterule ^convert$                           convert.php [L]
Rewriterule ^help$                          help.php [L]
Rewriterule ^login_process$                         login_process.php [L]
Rewriterule ^search_advanced$                   search_advanced.php [L]
Rewriterule ^verification_image$                    verification_image.php [L]

#search result
Rewriterule ^search/(.*)$ search_results.php?q=$1 [L]

#classified detail
Rewriterule ^classified/(.*)$ classified_details.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is it on the same IP address as the old site?

Comment: How are you issuing the redirect from the old site to the new one? And what type of hosting is this (vps, shared...trying to determine if you have access to the actual web server config)?

Comment: Its different IP address. I think I have access to web server config, they are using plesk so would need a bit more time to research,really hate plesk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to redirect all but a given IP, you can add a condition to your redirect for example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx$
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

For multiple IP's:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Or if the IPs have the same block 192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.2, 192.168.0.3:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Change `xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx` to your client IP.

However this would give you a few issues, for instance:

1. you client could have cached the redirect already, so you would need to ask him to use a different browser temporary or clear his cache (which doesn't always work).
2. If you have deleted the old rules it possible had on the .htaccess it would not work as expected.
3. if your client have dynamic IP you would need to change that every time he tries to access it.

There is probably more but this are the most common.

Comment: shift + reload does always work. also you can disable automatic redirects.

Comment: @hakre `shift+reload` not really it depends on a set of things including localization of system.

Comment: well, if you disable automatic redirects in your browser, you always have the chance to shift+reload as the URL has not yet changed.

Comment: Yes but then again I would rather want to refrain from doing that on a client's PC.

Comment: One easy way to do is using some proxy, browsers make it easy to enable / disable them for certain domains. The proxies IP address then could be used to signal which version to choose. Also perhaps the caching issues are gone, but I dunno if the browser cache differs on proxy.

Comment: @hakre well there are other ways too but, I would try to do it the easiest way possible not to over complicate the client's life as in having them place ANY sort of configuration on their machine or have to do anything other than simple access the website. Both answer, mine and anubhava are subjected to be cached, however it would be only temporary and just using a different browser would break that off.

Comment: This sounds like it would really work. How would I add multiple IP addresses ? And I really appreciate this guys, it took me hours today and in stack i get answer in matter of seconds...

Comment: Actually you don't need the OR ;) my bad have changed it according.

Comment: Great, just testing it now

Comment: Its working, awesome :) just added https as its https. Thanks Prix!

Answer (score 1):

One simple way of achieving this is by **passing a secret query parameter by your client**: (you can make it more complex as needed)

```
# set a cookie only if a secret URL e.g. http://oldsite.eu?q=q1w2e3r4t5
# is passed
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)q=q1w2e3r4t5(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,CO=mredir:0:secret]

# if cookie isn't set then redirect to new website
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*mredir=0.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.eu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://newsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

#### EDIT

Looked at your .htaccess and I would strongly suggest you to combine your multiple `Rewriterule` lines. See an example below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Rewriterule ^(index|login|register|help)$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: This sounds great! If he continue to surf through the site, would he still keep him on it or would he eventually get redirected ?

Comment: @GoranJakovljevic he would eventually get redirected depending on the other rules you may possible have on the file, for example if a rule removes that query string from the URL.

Comment: Looked at your .htaccess and I would strongly suggest you to combine your multiple `Rewriterule ^anything$ anything.php [L]` lines into one using OR condition using pipe `|` (see a sample in my edit above)

Comment: Also to answer your first question client will get old website **ONLY when using that secret query string** otherwise it will be redirected to new website. (We can aso set some cookie based on this secret query string using inside .htaccess)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to do redirection on everyone except specific ip maybe ?

Yes, that is perfectly possible. And I actually suggest you to do it that way because it is most easy to use. Alterantively you can *also* look for specific request headers so that the customer can view the old or new site and can control that. Another way is with cookies.

Now in concrete this is done depends a bit on the concrete webserver you're using, but most webservers are able to handle such configurations.

E.g. if you're using Apache HTTPD with mod_rewrite based redirects, you can formulate a RewriteCond accordingly.